# bootstrap grids in internet explorer 7

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-7, grid-system

Struggling with IE7 improperly wrapping columns in my Bootstrap 3, 3-column layout.

My grid-system works the way that I would like (stacking when in a resolution that reflects a smaller device) in every other browser including IE8.  I'd like to figure out what support I'm losing from IE8 to IE7 that is causing it not to wrap properly in IE7 which displays any column that has a portion of it's content in the 9+ position of the column on a new line.

```
< col-md-3 >< col-md-3 >< col-md-3 >
```

displays as:

```
< col-md-3 >< col-md-3 ><br />
< col-md-3 >
```

---

**Solution**

Boostrap 3 uses padding-left/padding-right on each of the column elements while also using < style = "width:100%;"> to achieve a consistent structure.

IE7 doesn't render this padding space properly and instead renders it as other browsers would margin space.  i.e. if the parent container is 960px wide, the width of the children PLUS the added margins must be less than 960. In essence (960/3)!=((320+margins)*3).

To overcome the issue I wrapped each column in a fixed width container.

Comment: You''re going to have a very hard time finding support for IE7, most sites no longer support this *very* old browser. Why do you have to support it?

Comment: customer of the site believes in technology that will last so they like legacy support

Comment: time to get a new cusotmer

Comment: Microsoft doesn't even support IE7. The latest they will support is IE9. You *could* have a stylesheet for IE7 load that will hide line breaks. Not the best method, but that's certainly not the best browser to be using anyway. Also, http://theie7countdown.com/ - less than 1% of the world uses it...

Maybe your client has failed to realize that the people using IE7 still are probably in a remote area of the world that will never use their services/products and if they would, they are used to everything on the internet looking like crud.

Answer (score 0):

Like Aibrean mentions, best solution is likely to create a separate stylesheet just for IE7. Try using conditional comments:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/path/to/ie7styles.css' />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: This is a good solution if there were multiple aspects of the CSS that I would have to change or if the css provided with twitter-bootstrap-3 were not as lengthy of a document to edit JUST to appease less than 1% of the populations (as Aibrean and Dan pointed out). Thanks for the heads up though

Answer (score 0):

IE8 and below do not support some of the selectors used in the Bootstrap stylesheet.  One of the most prominent examples of this is nth-child pseudo-selector which is used extensively in Bootstrap and not supported by IE8 and below.

---

*Following is not explicitly relevant to your issue but perhaps you can relate:*

Recently I had an issue whereas I generated a series of li.span4's in a jQuery loop.  In Bootstrap there is a rule to remove the margin-left from the 4th element but that rule is defined as nth-child(4) so is not relevant for IE8-

To overcome the issue I just found the rule that IE8 was not recognizing and supplemented it with another rule, defining the exact same thing without the psuedo-selector so where

```
[class*="span"]:nth-child(4)
```

existed, I supplemented:

```
.row-fluid > .span4:first-child + .span4 + .span4 + .span4
```

to achieve the same thing.  First-child is supported in IE8, not sure about IE7.